# Css in a new page in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

My css work fine in main page of my site but im facing a problem in the other page.

inside the views there is a *Welcome_message.php* inside of it is my css links..

in my views folder i have a folder named templates, inside it there are a header.php, main_nav.php and footer.php

in my controller folder there are 2 php files name*d Welcome.php* which is the `default_controller` that set inside the *routes.php* and the *staff.php* that the css wont work.

i have also a folder inside the views that name staff folder. inside of it i have a *staff-body.php*

here is my code in controller staff.php

```
class staff extends CI_Controller { 

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $data['title'] = 'NMSC Online Library';
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/main_nav');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

}
```

in my views/welcome_message.php code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Multi-Level Push Menu: Off-screen navigation with multiple levels" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="multi-level, menu, navigation, off-canvas, off-screen, mobile, levels, nested, transform" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/demo.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/icons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/component.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/my_style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/table.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"/>
</head>
```

in first run in my mainpage its work will with my css but when i click the button that link in the staff.php in controller, only the text show not the css.

Comment: And the view for staff.php reloads the css?

Comment: yes.. from Doctype to end tag of html... including the css... i dont know why.. help...

Comment: Without seeing all your view and css code it's pretty hard to do. A browser based debugging tool (Firebug for Firefox, Developer Tools for Chrome) may help you see what (if any) styles are applied to the elements in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In view create file call `header.php`. Inside that place

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Multi-Level Push Menu: Off-screen navigation with multiple levels" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="multi-level, menu, navigation, off-canvas, off-screen, mobile, levels, nested, transform" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/demo.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/icons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/component.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/my_style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url();?>icj/css/table.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"/>
</head>
```

and in controller

```
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('templates/body');    
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

There is an **order to be load view**.

1. Head of page
2. Body of page
3. Tail of the page

Comment: thanks for the reply sir. but the order of my page is mean_nav, header, body and footer.. because my nav menu is on the left side of the page that automatically show if the button is click... i tried that order that you given but my css is not working..

Comment: load page and check your page source. in thta click link and see its opend

Comment: i check the page source and i see the css link is loaded also my header main_nav content-body and footer are loaded in that staff page.. I wondered why my css dont work even its loaded already..

Comment: it wnt happen. if site loaded all the images will load